# Spring can't listen SessionDisconnectEvent

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I made a demo referring to this project ([websokets-spring](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring)),I mainly added WebSocketListener，this is my code

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketListener {

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectEvent sessionConnectEvent) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(sessionConnectEvent.getMessage());
        log.debug("connect, sessionId = {}", headerAccessor.getSessionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketConnectedListener(SessionConnectedEvent sessionConnectedEvent) {
        log.debug("connected ");
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent sessionDisconnectEvent) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(sessionDisconnectEvent.getMessage());
        log.debug("disconnect, session id = {}", sessionDisconnectEvent.getSessionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketSubscribeEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent sessionSubscribeEvent) {
        log.debug("subscribe, {}", sessionSubscribeEvent.toString());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketUnsubscribeEvent(SessionUnsubscribeEvent sessionUnsubscribeEvent) {
        log.debug("unsubscribe, {}", sessionUnsubscribeEvent.getSource());
    }
}
```

When I enter the page to open the WebSocket connection and close the WebSocket connection or Close page, I can listen to the event。[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOSak.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQdf5.png)

But when I use the front-end and back-end separated projects to connect WebSocket, I can listen to the SessionConnectEvent, but not the SessionDisconnectEvent[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b74ZR.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf1LW.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyt8m.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pevl.png)this is my front-end stomp code

```
function chatClient(): CompatClient {
    const socket = SockJS('http://localhost/ws');
    const client = Stomp.over(socket);
    return client;
}
client = chatClient();
  client.connect(
      {
        Authorization: getAuthorization(),
      },
      (frame: any) => {
        console.log("ws success", frame);
        client.subscribe(`/user/${userStore.userInfo.username}/messages`, function (message) {
          console.log('msg', message.body);
        });
      }, (err: any) => {
        console.log("ws err");
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a proxy across domains, you need to enable websocket true

```
server: {
            proxy: {
                '/api': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    // rewrite: (path: string) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
                },
                '/ws': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    ws: true
                }
            },
            // port: 80,
            open: false,
            fs: {
                strict: true,
            },
        }
```